# Extracting raster pixel data in QGIS for project analysing deforestation rates

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, shape-area

very new to QGIS and GIS software in general. I'm using QGIS to obtain spatial data from raster data for a spatial econometrics project I'm working on.

I have 14 .tif images displaying change in forested area from a given year across Australia. The 14 images combine to form a mosaic of the country, and each pixel value displays the year in which deforestation occurred for a given pixel area (0 if no deforestation, 1 for year t+1 etc).

I need to separate the pixel data so that I can analyse deforestation changes in a given area, for each year. How do I go about separating the data? Currently, I'm leaning towards creating shapefiles for each pixel value in each raster and combining all shapefiles for a given year, before using these shapefiles to calculate deforestation area proportions in administrative areas. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: If you have a shapefile for your administrative areas, you can use the "Zonal histogram" tool from the Processing toolbox. This will create a new shapefile with fields listing the count of pixels with each value for each administrative area.

Comment: Awesome exactly what I was looking for, cheers @Jake